# The first button in a gridView of buttons is not changing colour

Tags: android, gridview, custom-lists

I am unable to get the first button in a gridView to change colour. The button works fine, and it operates as normal when it is clickd but it wont update the colour of the first button. I am using a custom list adapter to generate the gridView. This only seems to happen if I want to change it in real time, if i load the buttons at a later stage the buttons do change colour. I've tried to hard code it for the first button in the list but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

In Grid view First you have to create a custom adapter for it and then in the Override method "get View()" you will get the specific cell and then change its background color.

For Details click the link : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Ive got that in already, and it works for the other buttons in the the gridView. The button also works when clicked but it doesnt change colour. Thank you for your response.